# Building en français

Tags: usage, anglicismes

Dans un livre pour les enfants (Au même instant sur la Terre) j'ai rencontré la phrase :

> Au même instant à Dubaï, Nadia regarde des ouvriers construire de
>   nouveaux **buildings**.

Je ne savais pas que **building** peut s'employer en français.

Est-ce un anglicisme ? Est-ce un emploi plutôt figuré ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'après Larousse, c'est un anglicisme.
Employé surtout à propos des États-Unis : les buildings de Manhattan. Pour les immeubles de même type construits en France, on emploie plutôt aujourd'hui le mot tour : les tours de la Défense, dans la région parisienne.